# can anyone explain following opengl code?

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, graphics

Can any one explain how glvertex3fv works when the function call

```
GLfloat v[][8][3]={{{-1.5,-1.5,-1.0}, {-1.3,-1.5,-1.0}, {-1.3,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.5,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.6,-1.6,1.0}, {-1.4,-1.6,1.0}, {-1.4,-1.4,1.0}, {-1.6,-1.4,1.0}} ,

{{-1.3,-1.5,-1.0}, {-1.1,-1.5,-1.0}, {-1.1,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.3,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.4,-1.6,1.0}, {-1.2,-1.6,1.0}, {-1.2,-1.4,1.0}, {-1.4,-1.4,1.0}} ,

{{-1.1,-1.5,-1.0}, {-0.9,-1.5,-1.0}, {-0.9,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.1,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.2,-1.6,1.0}, {-1.0,-1.6,1.0}, {-1.0,-1.4,1.0}, {-1.2,-1.4,1.0}} ,

{{-1.5,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.3,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.3,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.5,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.6,-1.4,1.0}, {-1.4,-1.4,1.0}, {-1.4,-1.2,1.0}, {-1.6,-1.2,1.0}} ,

{{-1.3,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.1,-1.3,-1.0}, {-1.1,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.3,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.4,-1.4,1.0}, {-1.2,-1.4,1.0}, {-1.2,-1.2,1.0}, {-1.4,-1.2,1.0}} ,

{{-1.1,-1.3,-1.0}, {-0.9,-1.3,-1.0}, {-0.9,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.1,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.2,-1.4,1.0}, {-1.0,-1.4,1.0}, {-1.0,-1.2,1.0}, {-1.2,-1.2,1.0}} ,

{{-1.5,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.3,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.3,-0.9,-1.0}, {-1.5,-0.9,-1.0}, {-1.6,-1.2,1.0}, {-1.4,-1.2,1.0}, {-1.4,-1.0,1.0}, {-1.6,-1.0,1.0}} ,

{{-1.3,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.1,-1.1,-1.0}, {-1.1,-0.9,-1.0}, {-1.3,-0.9,-1.0}, {-1.4,-1.2,1.0}, {-1.2,-1.2,1.0}, {-1.2,-1.0,1.0}, {-1.4,-1.0,1.0}} ,

{{-1.1,-1.1,-1.0}, {-0.9,-1.1,-1.0}, {-0.9,-0.9,-1.0}, {-1.1,-0.9,-1.0}, {-1.2,-1.2,1.0}, {-1.0,-1.2,1.0}, {-1.0,-1.0,1.0}, {-1.2,-1.0,1.0}}};

GLfloat colors[][3]={{0.0,0.0,0.0}, //black

{1.0,0.0,0.0}, //red

{1.0,1.0,0.0}, //yellow

{0.0,1.0,0.0}, //green

{1.0,0.0,1.0}, //magenta

{0.0,1.0,1.0}}; //cyan ....

void polygon(int a,int b,int c,int d,int i)

{

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glColor3fv(colors[a]);

glVertex3fv(v[i][a]); //wt is the meaning of this line

glColor3fv(colors[b]);

glVertex3fv(v[i][b]);

glColor3fv(colors[c]);

glVertex3fv(v[i][c]);

glColor3fv(colors[d]);

glVertex3fv(v[i][d]);

glFlush();

glEnd(); }

void colorcube() {

polygon(0,3,2,1,i); //wt is the meaning of i

polygon(2,3,7,6,i);

polygon(0,4,7,3,i);

polygon(1,2,6,5,i);

polygon(4,5,6,7,i);

polygon(0,1,5,4,i);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Notice: This is the OpenGL immediate drawing mode. It's been deprecated and discouraged to use for almost 20(!) years. In 1996 OpenGL-1.1 introduced vertex arrays which were to be preferred over immediate mode ever since.**

glVertex is part of the old, deprecated OpenGL immediate drawing mode. Between a glBegin … glEnd block an arbitrary number of glVertex calls is used to draw primitives to the screen; to control the attributes of what is drawn any attribute setting call preceding the glVertex call "selects" what glVertex will then emit.

A vertex is the whole combinations of any attribute specified for it + its position.

First lets look at single points:

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS); /* for every call of glVertex draw a point */

/* tip the "pen" into a bucket of bright red */
glColor3f(1,0,0);
/* draw a point, with whatever color currently is set at 1,1,1 */
glVertex3f(1,1,1);

/* let's make the pen blue */
glColor3f(0,0,1);

/* wait, we want it to be green */
glColor3f(0,1,0);
/* only the last value set for an attribute matters.
 * so the point drawn at 0,1,0 will be green */
glVertex3f(0,1,0);

/* and so on */
/* ... */

glEnd();
```

The difference to drawing GL_POINTS to GL_LINES or GL_TRIANGLES is, that you have to emit pairs or triplets of vertices to actually something appear on the screen (all withing a glBegin, glEnd block).

Now often you have the data for the attributes contained in some larger memory buffer. In that case it makes more sense to just point the attribute setter functions to that memory instead of passing the parameters. This is denoted by the letter 'v' in the OpenGL call name. So

```
GLfloat red_green_blue[3][3] = {
   {1,0,0},
   {0,1,0},
   {0,0,1}
};

glColor3fv(red_green_blue[0]) /* points to the 'red' part */
```

this would be equivalent to

```
glColor3f(
    red_green_blue[0][0],
    red_green_blue[0][1],
    red_green_blue[0][2] );
```

obviously the 'v' form is shorter and easier to read.

Now in your code it all boils down to dereferencing locations from an multidimensional array. You were wondering what 'i' means. I suggest you follow the code with pencil on a sheet of paper and figure out in which way what values go into OpenGL.

Comment: I tried to get the value of 'i' but i couldn't plz can u help me out 
U can find the code at [github link](https://github.com/punith21/qst.cpp/blob/master/qst.cpp)

Comment: @user2350539: Arrrrgh, who wrote this steaming pile of crap? `i` is a global variable, that's being abused to pass parameters into called subroutines (=functions). A normal parameter should have been used for that. Anyway in lines 246 and 299 you can find a for loop that iterates  the global variable `i` and calls `colorcube()` on it – why `i` isn't simply passed as a parameter is beyond me.

Comment: @user2350539: Here's a suggestion (also for you to improve your skills): At line 10 a set of global variables is defined, which are used for passing values into subroutines; replace them with variables in the local scope of the relevant functions and where required pass their values as parameters.

Comment: @user2350539: Also all the calls to `display` in the reshape handler, and the call of `glFlush` every other line or so in the drawing code is completely superfluous.

Comment: @user2350539: calling `glEnd` anywhere else than in closing a immediate mode drawing block started with `glBegin` is invalid.

Comment: @user2350539: I cleaned up the code a little bit: https://gist.github.com/datenwolf/f317685e32bf1332bf83 … It's still a heap of junk, but at least you can now see where the vertex index is supposed to come from. Seriously, if this is from an assignment or part of a class of data structures, whoever wrote this, clearly failed that very class. Anyway, I suggest you `diff` it against the original code to see the changes.